# match_parent won't work on children of a layout with minHeight

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-layout-weight

**Disclaimer:** I'm not able to reproduce this on all devices. I was able to reproduce it on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.1 and on a Galaxy Tab A. It doesn't happen on a Nexus 6 running 7.0, though.

Here's a minimum example to explain the situation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:minHeight="500dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000000" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some large text here aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
            android:textSize="100sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is a simple layout where I want my parent `FrameLayout` to take up all the space left by the `TextView` (that's why I have `android:layout_weight="1"`). If the `TextView` leaves a space smaller than the `FrameLayout`'s `minHeight`, than the content becomes scrollable and the `FrameLayout` sticks to its `minHeight`.

Everything works fine while content isn't scrollable, but if the `FrameLayout` reaches its `minHeight` and the content becomes scrollable, the child `FrameLayout` vanishes because its height becomes zero for some reason.

If you look at the Android Studio preview, you'll always be able to see the child `FrameLayout`, but when you run it (on some devices), you'll only see the parent's background.

The simplest solution is to add the same `minHeight` to the child `FrameLayout`, but in my case this isn't a good solution (my child is actually a custom view with some other child views).

Another solution is to force the child height in runtime:

```
private void ensureChildHeight() {
    parent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (parent.getHeight() > 0) {
                parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                if (parent.getHeight() == parent.getMinimumHeight()) {
                    child.getLayoutParams().height = parent.getMinimumHeight();
                    child.requestLayout();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But that's not great either. Does anyone know what's going on and whether there's a better solution for this? After working on it for some time and from my coworker's feedback, I feel `minHeight` is just not reliable and I should just avoid it whenever I can.

Comment: In your example XML your `ScrollView`'s single child has `match_parent` height, which is conceptually incorrect. Is this a contrived example or are you actually using `match_parent` for your ScrollView's child's height in your real layout?

Comment: Oh good point, I'll fix that. The behavior I described happens regardless of this, though. And I'm using `wrap_content` on my actual code.